# What is this arrange function in the second line doing here?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm currently reviewing R for Data Science when I encounter this chunk of code.
The question for this code is as follows. I don't understand the necessity of the **arrange** function here. Doesn't **arrange** function just reorder the rows?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13))
flights %>%
arrange(tailnum, year, month, day) %>%
group_by(tailnum) %>%
mutate(delay_gt1hr = dep_delay > 60) %>%
mutate(before_delay = cumsum(delay_gt1hr)) %>%
filter(before_delay < 1) %>%
count(sort = TRUE)
```

However, it does output differently with or without the arrange function, as shown below:

```
#with the arrange function
tailnum     n
   <chr>   <int>
 1 N954UW    206
 2 N952UW    163
 3 N957UW    142
 4 N5FAAA    117
 5 N38727     99
 6 N3742C     98
 7 N5EWAA     98
 8 N705TW     97
 9 N765US     97
10 N635JB     94
# ... with 3,745 more rows
```

and

```
#Without the arrange function
tailnum     n
   <chr>   <int>
 1 N952UW    215
 2 N315NB    161
 3 N705TW    160
 4 N961UW    139
 5 N713TW    128
 6 N765US    122
 7 N721TW    120
 8 N5FAAA    117
 9 N945UW    104
10 N19130    101
# ... with 3,774 more rows
```

I'd appreciate it if you can help me understand this. Why is it necessary to include the **arrange** function here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `arrange` just orders the rows but you are filtering  after that which changes the result.

Here is a simplified example to demonstrate how the output differs with and without `arrange`.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = c(7, 8, 9, 1, 2))

df %>% filter(cumsum(b) < 20)
#  a b
#1 1 7
#2 2 8

df %>% arrange(b) %>% filter(cumsum(b) < 20)
#  a b
#1 4 1
#2 5 2
#3 1 7
#4 2 8
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is great. But why is it necessary to use the arrange function here?

Comment: Originally data is sorted by `day`, `month` and `year`. Using `arrange` we first sort them by `tailnum` and within each `tailnum` the flights are sorted by `day`, `month` and `year`.